# Как сделать, чтобы функция срабатывала только при первом нажатии - Javascripr.

Tags: javascript

В javascript практически нуль. Поэтому подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы какая-либо функция срабатывала только при первом нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: @TimeNeedier, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ с удалением свойства объекта.

```
var obj = {};
    obj.toggle = true;
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){      
      if(obj.toggle){
        alert("clicked!");
        delete obj.toggle;
      }
    }
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/paperstreet7/jncEe/3/)

Способ второй. С удалением обработчика клика. Более красивый. Не работает в IE, но это не проблема.

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){  
    alert("Clicked!");
    this.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee, false); 
}, false);
```

Оба способа работают до перезагрузки страницы. Если нужно чтоб после перезагрузки кнопка тоже не нажималась, надо ставить куки.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!)